# AndEngine Moving a Connected Texture and Physics Body

Tags: 2d, android, textures, box2d, andengine

In AndEngine, many times we create a TextureRegion for our sprite.  We can move this region around the scene but when I connect that region to a physics body I end up being able to use either one to move around.

My question is, which one do I move around.  Should I use the physics body's position or the Texture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I think this is referenced [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post29963.html#p29963), and if not there's a decent community over there to ask. Even a bunch of tutorials/examples documented.

2) If I'm not mistaken I think you should always use transforms/forces to move anything associated with a body to correctly step with the Box2D physics...

Comment: I would vote this up but I don't have enough reputation points. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Free Lancer:+1 ;-)...